# error show TCItag in eqnarrary in \input{tcilatex}

Tags: tags

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{tcilatex}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{lemma}
The Binet formulas for these sequences are%
\begin{eqnarray}
P_{k,n}(x) &=&\frac{\alpha ^{n}(x)-\beta ^{n}(x)}{\alpha (x)-\beta (x)}, \TCItag{2.6} \\
Q_{k,n}(x) &=&\alpha ^{n}(x)+\beta ^{n}(x),  \TCItag{2.7} \\
q_{k,n}(x) &=&\frac{\alpha ^{n}(x)+\beta ^{n}(x)}{2},  \TCItag{2.9}
\end{eqnarray}%
\end{lemma}
```

## error show like this

```
Undefined control sequence.
l.194 ...a ^{n}(x)}{\alpha (x)-\beta (x)}, \TCItag                                              {2.6} \\
```

==============================

Comment: Do you actually have access to and use the tcilatex files? The come from scientific workplace and is generally not used outside sw

Comment: are you sure the command is called `\TCItag` ?  also why are you numbering the equations by hand rather than simply letting latex number them as it would by default?